# LSTM with normally distributed data

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am running an lstm model. My data has a predictor variable which is normally distributed.

I was just wondering using LSTM on such distribution is a good idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally distributed is pretty much symmetrical about its mean. For that reason, using Gaussian Naive Bayes would be better to choose.